# What's the difference between 'prop:TypeOrInterface' and 'prop<TypeOrInterface>'?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm starting to study Typescript and one of the things that I haven't catch yet is the difference between

`prop:TypeOrInterface`

and

`prop<TypeOrInterface>`

Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: Huge difference. In the second example, `TypeOrInterface` is a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). If you don't know what that is, you have some reading to do :)

Comment: Thanks Steven, going to read right now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be that in the first case `prop:TypeOrInterface` is a [type annotation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-annotation) and in the second case `prop<TypeOrInterface>` would be a [generic type construction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

`let a: TypeOrInterface` says that the variable `a` has type `TypeOrInterface`

`let a: GenricType<TypeOrInterface>` says that the variable a has type `GenricType` and that `GenericType` receives an argument of type `TypeOrInterface`. One way you can interpret this is that generic types are like function but in the type world